# Just doing some JQuery AJAX and I'm going step by step, but I keep getting a 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm just trying to test out JQuery AJAX and I'm going about it slowly. I open up the file on browser and use chrome dev tools to find find out what's going on, and it says that the status code is 404. This tells me that my GET is going nowhere? Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{$(".search button").click(function()
{getWeather(
    $(".search-bar").val()
)}
)}
);

function getWeather(city) {

var metric = "&units=metric";
var myAPI = "4f41b20d31ef924373402ebf9b9fe310";

var url="api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + city + metric + "&appid=" + myAPI;

$.getJSON(url, function(data)

{
    console.log(data);

})

}
```

I checked my url and everything but I keep getting the same thing. Is there something wrong with my code so far? It's a simple code right now but I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: `url` needs to begin with `//` or `https://`. You can leave these things out in the browser address bar, but not in code.

Comment: The way you've written it, it thinks `api.openwearthermap.org` is a subdirectory on your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the root of the URL:

```
var url="//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + city + metric + "&appid=" + myAPI;
//       ^-- here
```

Otherwise, when you tell the browser to make a request to `api.openweathermap.org`, structurally that's no different than making a request to `index.html` or any other resource on your own server.  Without specifying `//` to indicate that this is a different host, the browser is going to request this from the current host relative to the current page, which may become something like:

```
https://localhost:12345/mypracticeproject/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=...
```

Which *probably* isn't what you wanted.  You don't need to include the full protocol (`http` or `https`), but do at least need to include `//`.

Comment: That's exactly what it was, thanks. It's the small things that are easy to miss sometimes I guess.